# Why does Java and Javascript Math.round(-1.5) to -1?

Tags: javascript, java, rounding, negative-number

Today, I saw this behaviour of Java and Javascript's Math.round function.

It makes 1.40 to 1 as well as -1.40 to -1

It makes 1.60 to 2 as well as -1.60 to -2

**Now, it makes 1.5 to 2.
But, makes -1.5 to -1.**

I checked this behaviour in round equivalents of PhP and MySQL as well.
Both gave results as expected. i.e. round(-1.5) to -2

Even the [Math.round definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp) says it should round it to nearest integer.

Wanted to know why is it so?

Comment: nearest integer, means the nearest upper integer. `-1` is greater than `-1.5`.

Comment: @Tunki: Shouldn't there be a mention for same? They just said "nearest integer" not "nearest upper integer"

Comment: You can find this in [`RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN) docs: *This rounding mode is analogous to the rounding policy used for float and double arithmetic in Java.*. Otherwise, refer to [4.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) of the Java spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounding mode to round towards negative infinity. If the result is positive, behave as for RoundingMode.`DOWN`; if negative, behave as for `RoundingMode`.UP. Note that this rounding mode never increases the calculated value.
It is just matter of whole number and its position against number chart. From [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) you can see `javadocs`.

```
public static int round(float a)
```

Returns the closest int to the argument, with ties rounding up.

```
Special cases:
```

- If the argument is `NaN`, the result is 0.
- If the argument is negative infinity or any value less than or equal to the value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the result is equal to the value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.
- If the argument is positive infinity or any value greater than or equal to the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, the result is equal to the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

  Parameters:

a - a floating-point value to be rounded to an integer.

```
Returns:
```

the value of the argument rounded to the nearest int value.
Review this [link too](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)

Comment: It is better to include the relevant quote from the javadoc, than just a link.

Comment: I think you should link to [round](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)), too. Not just RoundingMode.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the distance between 1 and 1.5 as well as 1.5 and 2 is exactly the same (0.5). There are several different ways you now could round:

- always towards positive infinity
- always towards negative infinity
- always towards zero
- always away from zero
- towards nearest odd or even number
- ... (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding))

Obviously, both Java and JS opted for the first one (which is not uncommon) while PHP and MySql round away from zero.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ecma script documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.15),

> Returns the Number value that is closest to x and is equal to a
>   mathematical integer. If two integer Number values are equally close
>   to x, then the result is the Number value that is closer to +∞. If x
>   is already an integer, the result is x.

where x is the number passed to `Math.round()`.

So `Math.round(1.5)` will return 2 hence 2 is closer to +∞ while comparing with 1. Similarly `Math.round(-1.5)` will return -1 hence -1 is closer to +∞ while comparing with -2.